# Falha ao instalar o Electron no windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, windows-10

Estou tentando instalar o Electron no windows 10 usando estes comandos:

```
- git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
- cd electron-quick-start
- npm install && npm start
```

Estou seguindo os passos deste [**site**](https://electronjs.org/), mas mesmo assim estou recebendo esses erros:

```
> electron@6.0.11 postinstall C:\Users\System\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

'node' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@6.0.11 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@6.0.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Até o momento atual, o node que utilizo está o mais atualizado possível com a versão **10.16.3** e o npm **6.11.3**.

O que devo fazer para resolver esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'node' não é reconhecido como um comando interno

Quando dá esse erro, geralmente é o *PATH* do windows, que precisa adicionar mais esses caminhos:

%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin

%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/npm

Caso não saiba como alterar o PATH, aqui vai um tutorial rápido:

Basicamente você tem que acessar as variáveis de ambiente, independente do Windows que você estiver usando.

Clique no botão direito no Computador e escolha Propriedades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolha "Configurações Avançadas de Sistema"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai abrir a seguinte janela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em variáveis de ambiente, a seguinte janela abrirá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione *Path* e clique em editar

Comment: Obrigado pelo tutorial. O erro do node sumiu, mas agora apareceu um outro erro de **tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at ClientRequest.onError** O que poder ser isso, vc tem alguma ideia?

Comment: " tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 at ClientRequest.onError O". Esse erro ocorre em qual momento?

Comment: Quando eu dou npm install após ter baixado o electron do github. Aqui tem mais detalhes https://pastebin.com/8FaPWY2K

Comment: Geralmente isso é problema de proxy, se tu não usa proxy, tenta usar esse comando: >npm config set proxy null
>npm config set https-proxy null

Comment: @sYsTeM não esquece dar um upvote na minha resposta :D

Comment: Se tiver um proxy, ai tu usa o seguinte comando: >npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
>npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
Não esquece de ver se é http ou https

Comment: Obrigado cara, aqui funcionou na mosca